# Set value is object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, selection-sort

I want to put obj into value ex. `<option value={valueSort}>// valueSort = {name: 'ASC'}`
for use to sort by name in my project but now the result that is [object Object]. I don't know what is mean

react file `a.tsx`

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const a = () => {
const [filterType, setFilterType] = useState('');

const valueSort = {
nameASC:{ name: "ASC" },
nameDESC:{ name: "DESC" },
}

return (
<select
 onChange={(e) => {
  setFilterType(e.target.value);
  }}
>
  <option value={valueSort.nameASC}>By A - Z</option>
  <option value={valueSort.nameDESC}>By Z - A</option>
</select>
)}
export default a
```

controller file `a.controller.ts`

```
@Get('/')
async page(@Query() query: PaginateDto) {
const { sort } = query;
console.log('controller = ' + sort);
const sortby: any = sort;
return await this.aService.find(sortby);
```

service file `a.service.ts`

```
find(sort) {
 console.log('service = '+sort);
 return this.aModel.find().sort(sort).exec();
}
```

now the result in console log is

```
controller = [object Object]
service = [object Object]
```

I want the output in finally is

```
controller = { name: "ASC" }
service = { name: "ASC" }
```

for use sort by name

Comment: you can do `JSON.stringify(valueSort.nameASC)`

Comment: which add this code ? a.controller.ts file?

Comment: you want to show as option value right ? 

`<option value={JSON.stringify(valueSort.nameASC)}>By A - Z</option>`

Comment: it can show but this code not run sort function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining you sort options like this:

```
const valueSort = {
 nameASC: { name: "ASC" }, 
 nameDESC: { name: "DESC" },
}
```

This means, that when you are using `valueSort.nameASC` OR `valueSort.nameDESC` you are actually using an object.

When trying to add a value `<option value={valueSort.nameASC}>` you are trying to assign an object and that doesn't work (not directly).

It's not clear why you are trying to use an object and not a string. But if you still need to use an object, then you need to serialize that. The simplest way would be to use `JSON.stringify`. Something similar to this:

```
  <option value={JSON.stringify(valueSort.nameASC)}>By A - Z</option>
  <option value={JSON.stringify(valueSort.nameDESC)}>By Z - A</option>
```

Then use `JSON.parse` anywhere before being able to use these values.